# Regex extractor or any suitable object

Tags: rest, jmeter

Have a JSON response with list of Ids want to pick one from the group(JSON array) for the workflow. Used Regex extractor in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) for JSON response.

> The JSON PostProcessor enables you extract data from JSON responses using JSON-PATH syntax. This post processor is very similar to Regular expression extractor. It must be placed as a child of HTTP Sampler or any other sampler that has responses.

Comment: Thanks Jahan for the idea